# Endomorphisms which commute with any other endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $E$ be a vector space, and $C(E)=\{f \in \mathcal{L}(E) | \forall g \in \mathcal{L}(E), f \circ g=g\circ f\}$. Does $C(E)=Vect (Id)$?

In other terms, are the endomorphisms of a vector space which commute with any other endomorphism equal to $\lambda Id$, with $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$?

**My attempt:**

I was only able to prove this if $E$ is finite-dimensional, let's say $\dim E=n$.

Let $f \in C(E)$; then, we can write $A=(a_{ij})_{1 \leq i,j \leq n} \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ the matrix of $f$ in a basis of $E$. We therefore have:
$$\forall g \in \mathcal{L}(E), f \circ g = g \circ f$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \forall B \in M_n(\mathbb{C}), AB=BA$$
In particular, I will consider the matrices $E_{ij}$, which have a $1$ on position $(i,j)$ and $0$ anywhere else. Hence, $\forall i \in [|1,n|]$:
$$AE_{ii}=E_{ii}A$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \forall i \neq j, a_{ij}=0$$
Indeed, $AE_{ii}$ is the matrix $A$ without all its columns, except the $i$-th and $E_{ii}A$ is $A$ without all its lines, except the $i$-th. We now know that $A$ must be a diagonal matrix. For $i \leq n-1$, we can also write:
$$AE_{i,i+1}=E_{i,i+1}A$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \forall i \leq n-1, a_{i,i}=a_{i+1,i+1}$$
So, $A=a_{1,1} Id$; which means $\exists \lambda \in \mathbb{C}, f=\lambda Id$. It's easy to check that $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{C}, \lambda Id \in C(E)$. So $C(E)=Vect(Id)$.

If $E$ isn't finite-dimensional, I can't use matrices, and I'm not sure how to proceed further. Clearly $Vect(Id) \subset C(E)$, but I have no idea if the other inclusion is right - and if so, how to prove it. Could anyone help me?

Comment: What's stopping you from making this proof work in any dimension?  Let $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a basis of any cardinality.  Define the linear operator $E_{i,j}$ as the operator that sends $e_j$ to $e_i$ and all other basis vectors to zero.  Then proceed as before.

Comment: Oh right, this works exactly like matrices. So $C(E)=Vect(Id)$ in any dimension. Thanks!